How to fitler on text array column with supabase-js
I have a table i Supabase which looks like this:

I want to use supabase-js client library to filter on phone_numbers (which is a text array).
If I do like this:
const { data, error } = await supabaseClient.from('profiles').select('*').contains('phone_numbers', ["123456"])

I get no  result back.
If I do this in raw SQL it works (I get the row with id 2 back):
select * from profiles where phone_numbers @> array['123456'];

What am I doing wrong in the javascript filter?

Never mind, it was a RLS policy issue.
